# How to use dependent style names together with the CssResource obfuscation?

Tags: java, gwt, obfuscation, cssresource, clientbundle

I access the style names through CssResource, either from the UiBinder and from the java views. The problem is I cannot find a way to add and remove suffixes due to the class names obfuscation.

By the moment I've managed the situation using @external anotation on the primary and dependent names, but I don't consider is a good solution.

Comment: See this issue in the GWT issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4746.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right that the dependent styles can't work with CssResources, but you can achieve a similar effect with hierarchical styles, like

```
.widgetStyle .error {
  color: red; 
}
```

Then apply style.widgetStyle and style.error, instead of using a dependent name.